# using a zarr store as a fixed-size buffer

Tags: buffer, python-xarray, zarr

I'm trying to use a zarr store as a fixed-size buffer (i.e. new data is appended to the end, and the same amount of data is removed from the beginning when a certain size is reached).

The store is huge (20 TB), and contains a 2D matrix (positions over time).

Writing to zarr is handled by xarray.

However, I'm not sure whether zarr supports this.

I can think of two solutions:

- create a new xarray object from the first, eliminating the older data. However, writing that to disk will either append (`"a"`), leaving the older data intact, or overwrite (`"w"`), in which case I'm afraid the whole thing is rewritten which would not be performant for 20 TB.
- use [zarr.core.Array.resize](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/core.html#zarr.core.Array.resize), but this does not seem to allow dropping data at the start

Maybe zarr does not support this and I have to think of another solution, or writing my own store specifically aimed at this type of problem.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. It sounds like you are using Zarr's DirectoryStore on a posix filesystem, is that right? Have you seen https://medium.com/informatics-lab/creating-a-data-format-for-high-momentum-datasets-a394fa48b671?

Comment: Thank you for this invaluable reference! I think their solution might work for us, however they've not updated on this since 2019 so I wonder where it ended up getting them.